# HTML5 - Drag N Drop with divs and inner-images

Tags: drag-and-drop, draggable, html5-video

I have this type of element:

```
<div draggable="true" id="item" style="margin:20px;background:red;height:400px;width:400px;">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img style="margin:40px;" src="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to be able to:

1. Drag the whole div, even if I click on the /anchorimage (before dragging).
2. Still respond normally to an anchor/image click (without a drag).

Right now, only the image is dragged when I click on it.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M5tBd/

Answer (score 8):

As per the [HTML5 Editor's Draft spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/dnd.html), Images and Anchors with a href element are both elements that are, by default draggable. Your anchor is probably capturing the dragstart event, preventing the div from ever getting it. Try setting draggable="false" on your `<img>` and `<a>` elements.

```
<div draggable="true" id="item" style="margin:20px;background:red;height:400px;width:400px;">
<a href="#" target="_blank" draggable="false">
    <img style="margin:40px;" src="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" draggable="false">
</a>
```

Your fiddle doesn't even work dragging the img element for me in Chrome under Ubuntu, so you may have other issues besides this.

Comment: I've asked the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084387/how-to-html5-drag-an-element-that-has-a-link-in-it?noredirect=1#comment46401999_29084387 you might answer there and I'll accept it, as the OP here doesn't seem to care anymore.