# How to HTML5-drag an element that has a link in it

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have an element that has a link inside it and I want it to be draggable. The element looks like this:

```
<div draggable="true">
    <a href="#">122/1</a>
</div>
```

The dragging itself works fine, i.e. all expected events are fired. However when the user clicks on the link to drag, the element won't get dragged. In Safari and Chrome I see a grey box with rounded corners that contains the text and the `href` of the link, so it looks like I am dragging only the link and not the element. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xzroj7ey/4/. When clicking on the link to drag, the `div` still fires its `dragstart` event, but it doesn't get dragged.

How can I make the version with the link to be displayed correctly while dragging?

Comment: add `draggable="false"` to `a`

Comment: With this the link disappears while dragging :). Close but not quite right

Comment: nvm. CSS error. It works perfect. I would accept an answer :).

Comment: a gentleman answered something similar here, I learnt from there and suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030254/html5-drag-n-drop-with-divs-and-inner-images

Answer (score -1):

Add `draggable="false"` to `a`

```
<div draggable="true">
    <a href="#" draggable="false">122/1</a>
</div>
```