# Drag behavior of link inside div to be that of div

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

Say I have the following situation:

```
   <div draggable="true" ondragstart="behavior">
       Text <a href="www.google.com">Link</a>
   </div>
```

And I want the whole div to behave the same when dragged and dropped, how would I do this? The anchor tag seems to have it's own default behaviour that overrides the dragging on in the div. If I suppress that, by adding `ondragstart="return false"` I can't drag the div at all by dragging the link.

I suppose I could manually add the dragging behavior to the anchor tag so that it overrides the default behavior and matches the div behavior, but that seems kludgey.

I could also make a new tag to replace the anchor tag, but that also seems lame.

Is there a more elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this is the answer you are looking for: [HTML5 - Drag N Drop with divs and inner-images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030254/html5-drag-n-drop-with-divs-and-inner-images)

In short - add `draggable="false"` attribute to the link.